# Can't load the *.json file: (giving 404 File Not found)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, openrainbowapi

I am trying to setup the openrainbow API in my AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC application. There are two ways to configure and get connected with openrainbow API. [With AngularJS](https://api.openrainbow.com/sdk/web/tutorial-1-Getting%20Started.html) and [Without AngularJS](https://api.openrainbow.com/sdk/web/tutorial-6-Compatibility%20with%20non-Angular%20application.html)

I have configured it without AngularJS and it is working perfectly. But I want to configure it and get connected with AngularJS.

Given below is the code that I am using from the [API Documentation](https://api.openrainbow.com/sdk/web/tutorial-1-Getting%20Started.html).

**AngularJS Controller**

```
var sample = angular.module('sample', ['sdk']);

sample.controller("sampleController", [
  "rainbowSDK", 
  function(sdk) {
    "use strict";

    var onReady = function onReady() {
      console.log("[DEMO] :: Rainbow SDK is ready!");
    };

    var onLoaded = function onLoaded() {
      console.log("[DEMO] :: Rainbow SDK has been loaded!");

      sdk.initialize().then(function() {
        console.log("[DEMO] :: Rainbow SDK is initialized!");
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log("[DEMO] :: Something went wrong with the SDK...");
      });
    };

    $rootScope.$on(sdk.RAINBOW_ONREADY, onReady);

    $rootScope.$on(sdk.RAINBOW_ONLOADED, onLoaded);
  }
]);
```

---

**HTML VIEW**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-controller="sampleController">
<head>
    <title>OpenRainbow API</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="//api.openrainbow.com/sdk/web/libs/loader-sdk.min.js" data-main="./config.json"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**config.json file**

```
{
    "libraries": {
        "prerequisites": [
            "//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
            "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.15.1/moment-with-locales.min.js",
            "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"
        ],
        "sdk": {
            "official": [
                "//api.openrainbow.com/sdk/web/libs/vendors-sdk.min.js",
                "//api.openrainbow.com/sdk/web/libs/rainbow-sdk.min.js"
            ],
            "default": "official"
        },
        "after": [
        ]
    },
    "app": {
        "bootstrap": "sample",
        "key": {
            "appID":"",
            "appSecret":""
        },
        "js": [
            "./src/js/sdkSampleApp.js",
            "./src/js/components/connection/connectionCmp.js"
        ],
        "css": [
            "src/styles/sdkSampleApp.css",
            "src/js/components/connection/connectionCmp.css"
        ]
    },
    "settings": {
        "verboseLog": true,
        "disableCache": true,
        "enableLoader": true
    }
}
```

---

**Console Output:**

[image]

The data-main attribute is not loading the **config.json** file from the path. The path of the file is correct as the file exist on that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I used the following way to get it work. In my project's `web.config` file, I added the following lines for [MIME Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wawkw1c.aspx) to allow all JSON files. Now it is working perfectly fine.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

---

**Console Output:**

[image]